# How to create connection string to connect ax database in x++ of ax 7

Tags: x++, dynamics-365

I wrote code to connect ax database using SqlSystem class to create connectionstring. but it worked on developer environment not on production environment. How can I create database connection string so that work on both developer as well as production server. My code is as below :

```
 public str getConnectionString()
{
    var sqlInfo = SysSQLSystemInfo::construct();
    var loginServer = sqlInfo.getLoginServer();
    var loginDatabase = sqlInfo.getLogInDataBase();
    return strFmt('Server=%1;Database=%2;Trusted_Connection=true',loginServer,loginDatabase);
}
```

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: I will suggest you to create support ticket to Microsoft to see if the is supported scenario. As per my knowledge direct SQL access is not supported in D365 F&O.

Comment: If you are trying to access the production sql from a development machine, you will not be able to as Pradeep has already said. If you are just trying to execute raw SQL commands directly from X++, you can find an excellent example of that in the SrsStatementQuery class.

Comment: I am accessing right now local machine database for testing but when I am deploying this code on production server and trying to access it's database like azure sql server database the it is creating problem.

Comment: I want to know only, can I add condition to check it work with Windows credential or Sql server credential.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot connect to the production DB in the manner that you appear to be attempting to.

Long answer: Based on your comments on the question itself, it appears that you are trying to execute raw sql code or commands from x++. You will not be able to do it using the technique you have shown in the OP, and from your comment to "add condition to check it work with Windows credential or Sql server credential" - this will never work in production.

If my understanding is correct, and you are indeed attempting to execute raw sql from x++, I would look at the class SRSStatementQuery in the AOT for an example of an out of the box class that does this. Also, the following is a simplified version of this:

```
public static void main(Args _args)
{        
    Connection connection;
    Statement statement;
    SqlStatementExecutePermission permission;
    ResultSet resultSet;

    str sqlStatement = @"SELECT * FROM [%1].CUSTTABLE";

    sqlStatement = strFmt(sqlStatement, xSession::getDbSchema());

    connection = new Connection();
    statement  = connection.createStatement();

    permission = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(sqlStatement);
    permission.assert();

    // BP Deviation Documented - performing assert above
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);

    while (resultSet.next())
    {
        //process the results
    }
}
```